# Return a row of data based on the row above it

Tags: sql, hive

I have a table that has dates of when an action was taken on an account and what that action was.  I have ranked those based on the most recent dates by customer number.  The most recent instance is 1, one before that 2 and etc.  I would like to return all rows where the  rank = 1.  I would also like to return the rows where rank = 2 if the date field is populated and the date field in rank = 1 for that account is blank.

I have tried different variations of CASE WHEN and nothing I have tried seems to accomplish what I am trying.

For Example:

```
Account update_date chgoff_date chgoff_amt  rank
1234Z   6/12/2019   4/11/2019   63101.73    2
1234Z   7/12/2019   4/11/2019   63101.73    1
ABCD    6/12/2019   5/11/2019   12074.45    2
ABCD    7/12/2019                           1
ZXCV    6/12/2019                           2
ZXCV    7/12/2019                           1
```

For account 1234Z I should recieve the row with the 7/12/2019 update_date since its rank 1.

For account ABCD I should receive both rows, the first row because the rank is 1, but also the second row because the chgoff_date for rank 1 IS NULL while the chrgoff_date for rank 2 IS NOT NULL.

For account ZXCV I only want the row with 7/12/2019 update_Date and rank 1 because rank 2 for that account is also NULL.

I only need rank 2 row when it has a date and the rank 1 row does not.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry last answer was wrong, here is a new one that I think is correct:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT a.account,a.update_date,a.chgoff_date,a.chgoff_amt,a.rank1 
 FROM yourtablename a WHERE a.rank1 = 1 
UNION ALL
 SELECT account,update_date,chgoff_date,chgoff_amt,rank1 
 FROM yourtablename b where rank1 = 2 and chgoff_date IS NOT NULL 
 AND account in (SELECT account FROM yourtablename WHERE rank1 = 1 AND account = b.account AND chgoff_date IS  NULL) 
) qry ORDER BY account,rank1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, z44.nelther this worked perfectly and accomplished what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(chgoff_date) over (partition by account order by rank) as prev_chgoff_date
      from t
     ) t
where rank = 1 or
      (rank = 2 and
       prev_chgoff_date is null and
       chgoff_date is not null
      );
```